# The Cantor-BernsteinSchröeder theorem proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I don't understand this part underlined with red.Can someone explain it to me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g : B \to g[B]$ is injective (because $g : B \to A$ is) and surjective from the definition of $g[B]$. Every bijective function has an inverse.